# Error While Uploading Image to server using PHP

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to upload an image to a server by using php. But I'm getting following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 171:my server name/upload.php?sel_bar_code=ab12&text=hello&image=[encoded image to base64 comes hear]

I'm not getting this error on android. Below is my code that uploades images to the server.

```
if (isImage) {
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ByteArrayOutputStream ByteStream=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, ByteStream);
            byte [] b=ByteStream.toByteArray();
            image_value=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Background process code:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return uploadFile();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile() {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         // These params should ordered in key
            qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sel_bar_code", product_id));

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL+"sel_bar_code="+product_id+"&text="+text_value +"&image="+image_value);

            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {
                                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
                entity.addPart("website",
                        new StringBody("www.google.com"));
                entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("info@gmail.com"));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I develop the same process...

- The difference to my app need to send photos one by one. For the other hand, I send image bytes as String, at final I had problems with Base64 compression because the flag 'Base64.DEFAULT' adds intros in the string in my case. I solve this using flag 'Base64.NO_WRAP'. For omit this problem, you need to copy the file into public directory before send to verify that file is not corrupt.
- It's posible too that the server have a low size file that can send, the server part is which limit the size of files that receives.

If I can helped you tell me and good programming!